# Show compactness of an evolution operator

Tags: operator-theory, compactness, convolution

Consider the heat equation

$$
u_{t}=u_{xx},~~~~~u_0(x)=u(0,x)$$

with $u\colon [0,T]\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, (t,x)\mapsto u(t,x)$

and the evolution operator $E(T)$ with $E(T)u_0=u(T,x)$.

1.) Show that $u_0\star G_t$ with $G_t(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{4t})$ is a solution of the heath equation problem above.

2.) Show, that $E(T)\colon L^2([0,1])\to L^2([0,1])$ is a continuous and compact operator.

---

I already showed 1.) by solving the partial differential equation with Fourier transformation. So far so good.

But I do not come along with the compactness in 2.).

(I showed the continuity with the Young inequation  using the convolution - is that right?)

But how can I show the compactness of that operator?

Can anybody please help me?

Greetings

Comment: Ok for the continuity. For the compactness, the standard technique is showing that $E(T)$ is continuous as an $L^2([0,1])\to H^1([0,1])$ operator. The claim will follow from the compact imbedding of $H^1([0,1])$ into $L^2([0,1])$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Can you point to a reference on this matter? Since I'm working on a modified version of showing compactness of the heat semigroup operators over a slightly different space

Comment: @iYOA: It's been almost 9 years since that comment, and it is amazing that I am still here! Frankly I don't remember what I was thinking then. I'll have a look but I cannot guarantee anything

Comment: Much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: @iYOA: Yeah, it is not hard. Essentially you need to prove that the operator $f\in H^1\to e^{-x^2}\ast f\in L^2$ is bounded. Use Plancherel, so that $\lVert e^{-x^2}\ast f\rVert_2=\lVert e^{-\xi^2}\hat f\rVert_2$. And now multiply and divide by $\lvert\xi\rvert$ and then use Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thanks! Could you use Young's inequality directly on the convolution to bound the operator norm? And how does boundedness of the operator from H1 to L2 imply compactness? Maybe I'm missing something well-known.

Comment: No you can't use Young. That would give you L2 boundedness and no more. Concerning the other question, yes, it is easy. Composing a bounded operator with a compact one yields a compact operator.